# Call a command line tool in Python & Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, command-line, bioinformatics

I want to bring some of my GUI programs written for Windows in the Ubuntu software center. I'm using several external command line tools, which I call with

```
os.system(cmd)
```

No I want to know how I can do this under Linux (Ubuntu). Which corresponding file I have to use? In Windows the tool is just accessible in a folder of my program but not installed, will it work in the same way for Linux?

The tools which I need are all bioinformatic, [primer3](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/eprimer3.1e.html), [blast](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/blast.1.html), [bowtie](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/bowtie.1.html).

Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: If typing `primer3`, `blast`, or `bowtie` at the Ubuntu command line works, then `os.system` (or the more capable `subprocess`) will work as expected. Is there a reason you don't wish to "install" the binaries?

Comment: It's not so nice for the user to install several programs without knowing it, I thought. And also I don't know how to install it via Python. I defiantly don't like to ask the user to install 3 tools in addition. Is there an easier way?

Comment: If a user wanted to install your bioinformatics GUI on Ubuntu, wouldn't they likely be users of the command line tools? Absolutely flag them as dependencies, Ubuntu software center will inform the user and install them automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux, you usually package your applications so that they can be installed using the system package manager (for example, `.deb`  files for Debian-based distributions including Ubuntu and `.rpm` for RedHat). One reason (out of many) why you want to do this is dependency management – you can tell the package manager in your package on which other packages it depends, so that they can be installed if they aren't. You can do this using *setuptools*, there are many resources on this. In this case, you can expect the command line tools to be installed system-wide, and you can call them from your application.

If this is not possible, you could even include the source code of the tools you need and provide instructions for the user how to compile them (if necessary, inside your application directory). With most modern distributions, this is a rather painless process, but not exactly best practice.

---

Another note: `os.system` is blocking, it spawns a new process and waits for it to exit. You can't easily obtain the stdout or stderr output or interact with it. You should look into the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module (which is part of Python's standard library) or [`envoy`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/envoy) (3rd party module) which provides a simplified and (arguably) more powerful interface for the subprocess module.

If you want to "automate" command line tools, [`pexpect`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/2.4) makes you life much easier.

Comment: Ah, thanks for putting this into better words than I would have.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. Can you maybe tell me where to store the output created with dependencies?